# Drawing a hexagon grid with svg, using react to generate an infinite grid of hexagons, and the hexagons arent rendering correctly

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have the following react component that scrolls around an infinite grid of hexagons. The problem is that while panning left, right, and down correctly draws hexagons, panning up shows me different shapes (pictured below). The hexagons are what was rendered initially, and those shows that look like thick V's are the ones that render when I try to pan up. Any ideas?

```
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useWindowSize } from 'react-use';

export const Lisp = () => {
  const { width, height } = useWindowSize();
  const [panX, setPanX] = useState(0);
  const [panY, setPanY] = useState(0);
  const [panningEnabled, setPanningEnabled] = useState(false);

  const hexWidth = 100;
  const hexHeight = 100;

  const hexagons = [];
  const rowOffset = Math.floor(panY / hexHeight);
  const colOffset = Math.floor(panX / hexWidth);
  const numRows = Math.ceil(height / hexHeight) + 2;
  const numCols = Math.ceil(width / hexWidth) + 2;

  for (let row = rowOffset; row < rowOffset + numRows; row++) {
    for (let col = colOffset; col < colOffset + numCols; col++) {
      const x = col * hexWidth + (row % 2 === 1 ? hexWidth / 2 : 0) - panX;
      const y = row * hexHeight - panY;
      hexagons.push(
        <path
          key={`${row}-${col}`}
          d={`M ${x},${y + hexHeight / 2} 
              L ${x + hexWidth / 2},${y} 
              L ${x + hexWidth},${y + hexHeight / 2} 
              L ${x + hexWidth},${y + hexHeight / 2 * 3} 
              L ${x + hexWidth / 2},${y + hexHeight * 2} 
              L ${x},${y + hexHeight / 2 * 3} 
              Z`}
          fill="yellow"
          stroke="black"
        />
      );
    }
  }

  

  const handlePan = (event) => {
    if (panningEnabled) {
      setPanX((prevPanX) => prevPanX + event.movementX);
      setPanY((prevPanY) => prevPanY + event.movementY);
    }
  };

  const handleTogglePanning = () => {
    setPanningEnabled((prevPanningEnabled) => !prevPanningEnabled);
  };

  return (
    <Box width={width} height={height}>

<Box style={{
    transform: 'scale(2)'
}}>
    <svg width={width} height={height} onMouseMove={handlePan} onClick={handleTogglePanning}>
      <g transform={`translate(${hexWidth / 2}, ${hexHeight / 2})`}>
        {hexagons}
      </g>
    </svg>

</Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

[image: hexagons]

Comment: Is this for creating a background to the page or does the hexagons have a function -- like, should you be able to click on a specific hexagon or should they have different properties, like color?